# Behaviour of class members when threading inside a class

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have some code which sets up an interrupt handler in the main thread and runs a loop in a side thread. This is so I can Ctrl-C the main thread to signal to the loop to gracefully shutdown, and this all happens inside one class, which looks like:

```
class MyClass:
    # non-relevant stuff omitted for brevity
    def run(self):
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            future = executor.submit(self.my_loop, self.arg_1, self.arg_2)
            try:
                future.result()
            except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
                self.exit_event.set()  # read in my_loop(), exits after finishing an iteration
                future.result()
```

This works fine. My question is, are there are special types of objects or characteristics of objects I should be aware of with this approach, specifically regarding self. members on MyClass? I think it's fine because my_loop is spawned inside MyClass and so no copies of the self. properties are made - initial testing points this to be the case. I'm really wondering if there are any more exotic objects (eg non-pickleable, which does work fine in this) I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

As this is threads instead of between processes communication, pickleability does not matter as nothing is transmitted in queues. Your objects within your class (or outside the class) can be anything.

The only thing you need to keep in mind with class variables is that you need a lock to protect access to them. If you use several threads to modify a class variable, your results will eventually be something unexpected.